stdin:1: attempting to index null (global 'test.lua')
При попытке открыть файл через lua получаю ошибку:
stdin:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'test')
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?


прикрепите кусок кода, где открывается файл
